# CUDA kernel error when increasing thread number

Tags: c++, cuda, algebra

I am developing a CUDA ray-plane intersection kernel.

Let's suppose, my plane (face) struct is:

```
typedef struct _Face {
    int ID;
    int matID;

    int V1ID;
    int V2ID;
    int V3ID;

    float V1[3];
    float V2[3];
    float V3[3];

    float reflect[3];

    float emmision[3];
    float in[3];
    float out[3];

    int intersects[RAYS];

} Face;
```

I pasted the whole struct so you can get an idea of it's size. **RAYS** equals **625** in current configuration. In the following code assume that the size of faces array is i.e. 1270 (generally - thousands).

Now until today I have launched my kernel in a very naive way:

```
const int tpb = 64; //threads per block
dim3 grid = (n +tpb-1)/tpb; // n - face count in array
dim3 block = tpb;
//.. some memory allocation etc.
theKernel<<<grid,block>>>(dev_ptr, n);
```

and inside the kernel I had a loop:

```
__global__ void theKernel(Face* faces, int faceCount) {
    int offset = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if(offset >= faceCount)
        return;
    Face f = faces[offset];
    //..some initialization
    int RAY = -1;
    for(float alpha=0.0f; alpha<=PI; alpha+= alpha_step ){ 
        for(float beta=0.0f; beta<=PI; beta+= beta_step ){ 
            RAY++;
            //..calculation per ray in (alpha,beta) direction ...
            faces[offset].intersects[RAY] = ...; //some assignment
```

This is about it. I looped through all the directions and updated the **faces** array. I worked correctly, but was hardly any faster than CPU code.

So today I tried to *optimize* the code, and launch the kernel with a much bigger number of threads. Instead of having **1 thread per face** I want **1 thread per face's ray** (meaning 625 threads work for 1 face). The modifications were simple:

```
dim3 grid = (n*RAYS +tpb-1)/tpb;  //before launching . RAYS = 625, n = face count
```

and the kernel itself:

```
__global__ void theKernel(Face *faces, int faceCount){

int threadNum = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;

int offset = threadNum/RAYS; //RAYS is a global #define
int rayNum = threadNum - offset*RAYS;

if(offset >= faceCount || rayNum != 0)
    return;

Face f = faces[offset];
//initialization and the rest.. again ..
```

And this code does **not** work at all. Why? Theoretically, only the 1st thread (of the 625 per Face) should work, so why does this result in bad (hardly any) computation?

Kind regards,
e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum size of a grid in any dimension is 65535 ([CUDA programming guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf), Appendix F).  If your grid size was 1000 before the change, you have increased it to 625000.  That's bigger than the limit, so the kernel won't run correctly.

If you define the grid size as

```
dim3 grid((n + tpb - 1) / tpb, RAYS);
```

then all grid dimensions will be smaller than the limit.  You'll also have to change the way `blockIdx` is used in the kernel.

Comment: It seems this is it. Unfortunately, no performance gain noticed.. perhaps because of one more loop left inside the kernel. How would you divide (grid and blocks) when having: 1000 faces, each having 600 rays that have 1000 possible intersections?

Comment: You have already reached the limit on how many threads can execute in parallel.  Adding more threads won't make the kernel faster.  If you're trying to speed up the kernel, it may help to use a different data layout for memory coalescing.  Memory coalescing is described in the CUDA programming guide.

Comment: well, if I have more than 1024 items of anything, putting them in block is impossible, so shared memory is useless. In my case each face checks which faces it can 'see' - except itself - so the `if(x==self) continue` part will differentiate all the threads ;(

Answer (score 0):

As Heatsink pointed out you are probably exceeding available resources. Good idea is to check after kernel execution whether there was no error.

Here is C++ code I use:

```
#include <cutil_inline.h>

void
check_error(const char* str, cudaError_t err_code) {
    if (err_code != ::cudaSuccess)
        std::cerr << str << " -- " << cudaGetErrorString(err_code) << "\n";
}
```

Then when I invole kernel:

```
my_kernel <<<block_grid, thread_grid >>>(args);
check_error("my_kernel", cudaGetLastError());
```